# How to route somehost to other host with some port on linux?

Tags: linux, hosts, routing

Say I want to route all requests to google.com to localhost:333 , how to do so?

Comment: Interesting and suspicious question =).

Answer (score 3):

Shorewall routes. ([FAQ](http://www.shorewall.net/FAQ.htm))

You want to redirect all local google.com connection requests to a server running in your local zone at 127.0.0.1 and listening on port 333. Your local interface is eth1.

Disclaimer; I've not done exactly this with Shorewall, so modified an example Squid server setup:

1. Add this entry to your /etc/shorewall/providers file.

   ```
   #NAME   NUMBER  MARK    DUPLICATE       INTERFACE       GATEWAY         OPTIONS
   foo     1       202     -               eth1            127.0.0.1     loose
   ```
2. In /etc/shorewall/tcrules add:

   ```
   #MARK    SOURCE              DEST        PROTO    DEST
   #                                                 PORT(S)
   202:P    net:google.com   0.0.0.0/0   tcp      80
   ```
3. In /etc/shorewall/interfaces :

   ```
   #ZONE   INTERFACE    BROADCAST    OPTIONS
   loc     eth1         detect       routeback
   ```
4. On localhost, arrange for the following command to be executed after networking has come up

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d ! 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 333
   ```

Comment: redirecting google by hand-added IPs won't work very well -- you'll get a different IP for the DNS lookup every 5 minutes or so due to load balancing.  for google.com, you'd really want to reroute at the DNS level.  can Shorewall do that?

Comment: I suspect "net:google.com" should do the trick. Yeah, you caught me mid edit there.

Comment: fair enuff.  leaving the comment for the time being but glad to see you were working on it already.  :)

Comment: That's the best I can come up with I think. I'll leave it here for someone more experienced with shorewall to comment on / edit.

Comment: I want it to be on the same machine, so pinging google.com should go to some port that I specify on my local machine, say 333

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do this on a single machine, you can edit:

```
/etc/hosts
```

and add

```
google.com 127.0.0.1
```

then restart network services

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/network restart
```

This would redirect normal web traffic to localhost:80 though.

Comment: Nice idea to keep track of local network connections! :D

Comment: That's what I wanted originally but also I want to control to which port the request will go.